# Почему не отрабатывает catch у внутреннего промиса?

Tags: javascript, promise

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у внутреннего прописа не отрабатывает catch?

```
onFormSubmit = ({ email }: IFormValues) => {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.props
        .setProfile({ email })
        .then(() => {
          this.isEmailError = false;
          this.setProductSubscription(true)
            .then(() => resolve())
            .catch((errors: IError[]) => { // Вот этот catch 
              console.log('errors', errors) 
            });
        })
        .catch((errors: IError[]) => {
          return handleValidationErrors(errors);
        });
    })
  };

setProductSubscription = (isSubscribed: boolean) => {
    return this.props
      .setProductSubscription(this.props.productId, isSubscribed)
      .then(() => {
        if (isSubscribed && !this.state.isSidebarRendered) {
          Notification.success(createTranslatable('productSubscriptionSubscribedSuccessfully'));
        }
      })
      .catch((errors: IError[]) => {
        this.isEmailError = getValidationErrorByCode(errors, ERROR_CODE_NO_EMAIL)?.code === ERROR_CODE_NO_EMAIL;

        if (this.isEmailError) {
          return this.renderSidebar();
        }

        showValidationErrors(errors);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас ошибку уже обработал вот этот `catch`:

```typescript
.catch((errors: IError[]) => {
    this.isEmailError = getValidationErrorByCode(errors, ERROR_CODE_NO_EMAIL)?.code === ERROR_CODE_NO_EMAIL;

    if (this.isEmailError) {
        return this.renderSidebar();
    }

    showValidationErrors(errors);
});
```

Чтобы тот `catch` срабатывал, можно обернуть тело `setProductSubscription` в промис:

```typescript
setProductSubscription = (isSubscribed: boolean) => {
    return new Promise<void>((res, rej) => {
        this.props
            .setProductSubscription(this.props.productId, isSubscribed)
            .then(() => {
                if (isSubscribed && !this.state.isSidebarRendered) {
                    Notification.success(createTranslatable('productSubscriptionSubscribedSuccessfully'));
                }
                res();
            })
            .catch((errors: IError[]) => {
                this.isEmailError = getValidationErrorByCode(errors, ERROR_CODE_NO_EMAIL)?.code === ERROR_CODE_NO_EMAIL;
    
                if (this.isEmailError) {
                    this.renderSidebar();
                    rej(errors);
                    return;
                }
    
                showValidationErrors(errors);
                rej(errors);
            });
    })
};
```

Comment: да, вы правы, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 0):

catch выполнится если промис закончится ошибкой

Comment: Как раз таки ошибка в нем и происходит

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @bazmexes чем докажете, что происходит ошибка?